# JQuery selector to ignore an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am extracting article page content.

One selector, `"entry": $('div.content__article-body').html().trim()` gets the main article body.
This mostly comprises text paragraphs with their `<p>` and header tags, which is just what I want.
However, it also gets an element I don't want, which is `<aside>`.
How can I ensure `<aside>` is NOT included in the resulting text?

I have read threads on here about "not".
I have tried things like ...

```
$('div.content__article-body').not('aside').html().trim()

$('div.content__article-body').html().not('aside').trim()
```

`$('div.content__article-body:not(aside)').html().trim()` or `$('div.content__article-body:not('aside')').html().trim()` - not sure.

But none of these seems to work. Am I misforming how to use "not"?

**Update**: Excerpt below (`aside` is basically a box-out within the article)...

```
</figcaption>
</figure>
</header>
<div class="content__article-body from-content-api js-article__body" itemprop="articleBody" data-test-id="article-review-body">
<p>A wise man once <a href="http://www.quora.com/Who-originally-suggested-that-if-youre-not-paying-for-the-product-you-are-the-product" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">said</a>: “If you’re not paying for it, you’re the product.” That’s what is happening in the magazine world, as <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/media/2015/jul/06/nme-to-go-free-with-larger-circulation" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">NME abandons its cover price</a> after 63 years, to go free.<br></p>
<p>In doing so, the title is turning its readers from customers in to advertiser targets. But NME is far from the first property to try this trick. <a href="http://articles.baltimoresun.com/1996-11-13/features/1996318156_1_village-voice-schneiderman-circulation" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">The Village Voice</a>, the <a href="http://www.britishpapers.co.uk/england-wmids/shrewsbury-chronicle/" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">Shrewsbury Chronicle</a>, the <a href="https://news.google.com/newspapers?id=HU1aAAAAIBAJ&amp;sjid=KSgMAAAAIBAJ&amp;pg=1120%2C535142" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">Standard</a> of Hong Kong, <a href="https://gigaom.com/2007/10/31/419-friends-reunited-dropping-subscriptions-to-go-free-ad-supported-report/" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">Friends Reunited</a>, the <a href="https://gigaom.com/2009/10/02/419-london-evening-standard-bold-re-birth-or-a-free-folly/" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">Evening Standard</a>, the <a href="http://www.fulhamsw6.com/default.asp?section=info&amp;spage=common/contrinity001.htm" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">Fulham and Hammersmith Chronicle</a>, Time Out in <a href="https://gigaom.com/2008/09/01/419-time-out-seeking-investors-could-go-free-and-beef-up-online/" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">London</a> and <a href="http://www.timeout.com/about/time-out-group/latest-news/time-out-new-york-announces-launch-of-its-magazine-to-free-weekly-distribution" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">New York</a>, and now <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/media/greenslade/2015/jul/08/the-sun-lowers-its-paywall-allowing-free-access-to-many-stories" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">parts of the Sun’s website</a> are all among those to have dropped their fees in favour of frees.</p>
<p>But what has become of the converts? And what do their fortunes since tell us, <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/music/nme" data-link-name="auto-linked-tag" data-component="auto-linked-tag" class="u-underline">NME</a> and other operators about the key ingredients for a successful switch?</p>
<aside class="element element-rich-link element--thumbnail element-rich-link--not-upgraded" data-component="rich-link" data-link-name="rich-link-1 | 1">
<div class="rich-link">
<div class="rich-link__container">
<div class="rich-link__header">
<h1 class="rich-link__title">Old media's prospects have improved but the new media threat looms large</h1>
</div>
<div class="rich-link__read-more">
<div class="rich-link__arrow">
<span class="inline-arrow-in-circle inline-icon ">
<svg width="24" height="24" viewbox="0 0 24 24" class="inline-arrow-in-circle__svg inline-icon__svg">
<path class="rich-link__arrow-icon" d="M12 0C5.373 0 0 5.373 0 12s5.373 12 12 12 12-5.373 12-12S18.627 0 12 0m.21 19l-.637-.668 4.888-6.326H4.996v-1.01h11.465l-4.888-6.333.637-.668L19 11.153v.685l-6.79 7.157" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg> </span>
</div>
<div class="rich-link__read-more-text">
Read more
</div>
</div>
<a class="rich-link__link u-faux-block-link__overlay" href="https://www.theguardian.com/media-network/2015/mar/20/new-media-threat-buzzfeed-vice" aria-label="Old media's prospects have improved but the new media threat looms large"></a>
</div>
</div>
</aside>
<h2>1. Know your predicament</h2>
<p>It would be nice to say the switch to free comes either out of benevolence or out of a market opportunity. The reality is, operators invariably flick the switch under external pressure of a poor business outlook – no amount of dressing up as a “bold relaunch” can change that.</p>
<p>NME’s circulation was falling by <a href="https://www.theguardian.com/media/2014/feb/13/nme-relaunch-sales-slide-ipc-media" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">around a fifth annually</a>. The Evening Standard was frustrated to find itself far behind national dailies on ad planners’ schedules, locking it out of big brand bucks, according to someone familiar with the strategy to switch.</p>
<p>The Village Voice dropped its cover charge in 1996 after being eaten into by rival New York Press being given away in green sidewalk boxes, while Hong Kong’s Standard newspaper was forced to act when the government removed a decree that listed companies must buy classified ads in newspapers. But the key – as anyone who has heard the “<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boiling_frog" rel="nofollow" data-link-name="in body link" class="u-underline">boiling frog</a>” allegory will know – is to recognise when it is your time to change tack.</p>
```

Comment: Provide your HTML too, so we know how to suggest a proper answer.

Comment: In your selectors your selecting a div that is not `<aside>` it's not correct. Is the `<aside>` tag inside of `div.content__article-body` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `.not()` method, do like this, expand the selector to `div.content__article-body > *` so it target the `div`'s siblings, and then loop through the result.

*The usage of the child selector `>` allow to exclude any elements inside `aside` though that will also affect the other elements too, and to bring their children back in the output, use `.outerHTML`.*

Stack snippet

```js
$('div.content__article-body > *').not('aside').each( function( index, value ) {
  console.log( value.outerHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content__article-body">

    <p>some paragraph <span>some span</span></p>

    <div>some div</div>

    <aside>an aside <div>some div in aside</div></aside>

</div>
```

---

And with the `:not()` selector.

Stack snippet

```js
$('div.content__article-body > *:not(aside)').each( function( index, value ) {
  console.log( value.outerHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content__article-body">

  <p>some paragraph <span>some span</span></p>

  <div>some div</div>

  <aside>an aside <div>some div in aside</div></aside>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for responses. I am struggling to implement answers, likely due to my own level of Javascript proficiency. My set up works like `result = { "entry": $("jquery_selector_here") };` (multiple exist within `result`' I'm not sure how to reconcile this with the subsequent `value.outerHTML` line.

Comment: @RobertAndrews Could you manually create that object using my above demo code so I better understand the end result. Use e.g. a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/iamrobertandrews/6p0w1x5k/5/ Problems with it as I inserted. I'm not sure the console.log stuff is appropriate in my use case.

Comment: @RobertAndrews I think you misunderstood. I would like a sample of the end result, manually created from the code sample I showed above in my answer.

Comment: I think that's the problem - I don't understand how to. The three lines of your "not" code don't quite validate in the place I insert them.

Comment: @RobertAndrews Okay, so your initial _"How can I ensure `<aside>` is NOT included in the resulting text?"_ is answered, right?....Now it appears you also add a new question, _"How to generate an object with the elements found in a given jQuery selection, e.g. `$("jquery_selector_here")`"_. If that is the case, then kindly accept/upvote this answer of mine, as it answered your initial question, and then post another with your new requirements, as that is how one is suppose to do.

Comment: @RobertAndrews Also, in the new question, refer to this question, so the one's that will answer that, understand from where that next step came from.

Comment: @RobertAndrews And what I meant with a manual created object were something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/gpLoh46d/

Comment: Good form. I asked a new question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132541/how-to-generate-an-object-with-the-elements-found-in-a-given-jquery-selection

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
var e = $('.box').html();
console.log(e);

var subStr = e.match("<aside>(.*?)</aside>");
var r = e.replace(subStr[0], "");

console.log(r);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  Some text here
  <p>More text here</p>
  <aside>this is an <span>aside</span></aside>
</div>
```

Or you create another element then you remove the aside node:

```js
var e = $('.box').html();
var newE = $('<div>'+e+'</div>');
newE.find('aside').remove();
console.log(newE.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  Some text here
  <p>More text here</p>
  <aside>this is an <span>aside</span></aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Using regex to parse HTML is a BIG no-no :) ... and there is a proper usage for the asked method/selector, which I posted

Comment: @LGSon I added another one too ;) by the way your solution will not gather all the content within on Variable ... I think he's looking for a way to extract all the content minus the aside content ... in your case you can get also content inside the aside. So better use `>` I guess

Comment: I actually rewrote the answer, and thanks for the note about children inside `aside`, they can be taken out with multiple arguments using `.not()`

Comment: I were wrong about the child selector...how `console.log` printed it out it looked like all children were gone, but they weren't

Comment: Plus 1 from me...as in this new question it became more clear what the OP were looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51132541/how-to-generate-an-object-with-the-elements-found-in-a-given-jquery-selection

Answer (score -2):

Try this.

$("div.content_article-body *:not(aside)");